# The "dev" suffix in package names?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

When using apt-get I see some packages have a "dev" suffix after their names:

```
libreadline5
libreadline-dev
zlib1g
zlib1g-dev
```

What are these exactly and should I install them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need these to *compile and link* as they provide headers and libraries to link whereas the standard packages just contain the run-time versions.

Comment: Exactly.  If you are just *using* the library, get the non-"dev" version.  You only need the "-dev" version if you are using the lib in a program you are writing or if you are compiling an app from source.

Comment: What is meant exactly by 'run-time versions'? .so?

Comment: Yes.  The minimal content to permit _execution_. Typically just the shared library.  Where the `-dev` package has header files, often the static library, and the additional shared libray links -- all of which is needed for _building_ the program / package.  This split is common across all Linux distros.