# Python 3.6: how to install rubberband?

Tags: pip, python-3.6, python-wheel, rubber-band

I want to use [this](https://pyrubberband.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pyrubberband.pyrb.time_stretch.html#pyrubberband.pyrb.time_stretch) function, and I'm trying to install rubberband using pip as the following: `pip install rubberband`

But, it raises the following error: "Failed building wheel for rubberband"

And I can't use Python 3.5 in my project. So, how to install rubberband?

P.S. My OS is Windows 10, and I have python 3.6 on it.

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: @FlyingTeller It's too long, I'll past some important lines of errors:

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++17'

Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rubberband/RubberBandStretcher.h': No such file or directory

ERROR: Failed building wheel for rubberband

Answer (score 2):

To make a long story short, this is how I installed the rubberband python package.

1. `apt update`
2. `apt-get install libsndfile-dev`
3. `apt-get install librubberband-dev`
4. `python3 -m pip install numpy` (required for rubberband)

Note that the `-dev` postfix is required to get the header files that are later required for the python rubberband package to be able to compile the package.

Later, `pip install rubberband` failed on `transform is not a member of std`.
To solve that, I did the following:

1. `python3 -m pip download rubberband`
2. `tar -xf rubberband-1.0.2.tar.gz`
3. edit `rubberband-1.0.2/src/numpy.cpp` - add `#include <algorithm>` at the top of the file.
4. cd `rubberband-1.0.2` and then run `python3 -m pip install .` or better yet `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` to create a whl file to add to your docker dependencies.

Comment: Does `-dev` unstable, being developed package?

Comment: No, it just means the said package contains header files in addition to executables, so that you’re able to depend on it during development. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588164/the-dev-suffix-in-package-names

Answer (score 1):

The docs you pointed to are the docs for the project [pyrubberband](https://pypi.org/project/pyrubberband/), not `rubberband`. So install it with `pip install pyrubberband`.

As for `rubberband`: you probably need a C/C++ compiler to install it.

*Upd*. `pyrubberband` is a Python wrapper for [rubberband](https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/). You need to install it, see https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/index.html

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it gives the following error: "RuntimeError: Failed to execute rubberband. Please verify that rubberband-cli is installed.", and I tried to install rubberband-cli as the following: `pip install rubberband-cli`, and it gives the following error: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rubberband-cli (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for rubberband-cli". So how to solve that?

Comment: You need to install `rubberband`. It's not a Python package, you cannot install it with `pip`. See update in the answer.

Comment: I read your link, there is no obvious way how to install rubberband on Windows so that we can use pyrubberband in Python code without the mentioned error. Thank you.

Comment: @catfour you need to add the directory which has `rubberband.exe` and `libsndfile-1.dll` to your [PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho). I have it installed here: `C:\Program Files\rubberband-1.8.2-gpl-executable-windows`. You could alternatively just add those 2 files to a directory which is already in your PATH.

Answer (score -1):

If you ran through this and using `macOS`, brew for everything works

> $ `brew install rubberband`

Works like charm https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rubberband

Comment: This will not work on Windows though :(

Comment: `If you ran through this and using macOS, brew for everything works`

Answer (score -1):

Install "rubberband-cli" Package on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y rubberband-cli
```

Comment: also works for debian

Comment: But the topic starter asked for Windows solution